# How do I handle duplicate data when I run this macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I use this to create a list in Column B of my sheet. I would like to be able to change this to add the list starting at the bottom, so I can leave the existing data alone. This will create duplicates. I want the duplicates at the bottom removed leaving only NEW names.

I am a novice with VBA. I would appreciate some help.

Thanks!

```
Sub ListSubFolders()

'macro to pull folder names into the column

    Dim Cell        As Range
    Dim Folder      As Variant
    Dim SubFolders  As Variant
    Dim vArray      As Variant

        Set Cell = Range("B3")
        Folder = "R:\Bids\" & [C1]
                
        With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            Set SubFolders = .Namespace(Folder).Items
                SubFolders.Filter 32, "*"
        End With
        
        If SubFolders.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "There are No Subfolders in this Directory."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        ReDim vArray(1 To SubFolders.Count, 1 To 1)
        
        For n = 0 To SubFolders.Count - 1
            vArray(n + 1, 1) = SubFolders.Item(n).Name
        Next n
        
        With Cell.Resize(n, 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = vArray
        End With
        
 
    Range("B3").Select
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use a collection and loop to check for and remove duplicates. Lots of VBA examples online you can adapt for your use. https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/remove-duplicates-array

Answer (score 1):

### List Subfolders: Update Existing List

```vb
Sub ListSubFolders()
    
    Const RootFolderName As String = "R:\Bids\"
    Const SubFolderNameAddress As String = "C1"
    Const sFirstCellAddress As String = "B3"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim FolderName As Variant
    FolderName = RootFolderName & ws.Range(SubFolderNameAddress)
            
    Dim SubFolders As Object: Set SubFolders _
        = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(FolderName).Items
    SubFolders.Filter 32, "*"
    If SubFolders.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are No Subfolders in this Directory."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim rCount As Long
    
    ' Write the existing folder names to a dictionary.
    
    With ws.Range(sFirstCellAddress)
        Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then
            Set dCell = .Cells
        Else
            rCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 1
            Set srg = .Resize(rCount)
            Set dCell = .Offset(rCount)
        End If
    End With
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    If Not srg Is Nothing Then
        
        If rCount = 1 Then
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = srg.Value
        Else
            Data = srg.Value
        End If
        
        For r = 1 To rCount
            Key = Data(r, 1)
            If Not IsError(Key) Then
                If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                    dict(Key) = Empty
                End If
            End If
        Next r
    
    End If
    
    ' Write the new folder names to a collection.
    
    Dim Coll As Collection: Set Coll = New Collection
    
    Dim Item As Variant
    
    For Each Item In SubFolders
        Key = Item.Name
        If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then
            dict(Key) = Empty
            Coll.Add Key
        End If
    Next Item
    
    ' Write the new folder names from the collection to an array.
    
    rCount = Coll.Count
    If rCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
        
    ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    r = 0
    
    For Each Key In Coll
        r = r + 1
        Data(r, 1) = Key
    Next Key
    
    ' Write the new folder names from the array to the range.
    
    With dCell.Resize(rCount)
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value = Data
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Subfolder list updated.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```